# Probability of measuring a pure qubit state after some unitary rotation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability, quantum-computer

Suppose I have the prepared state
$$|+\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and the unitary $Z_{\pi/2}$ which rotates a state in the Bloch sphere by $+\pi/2$ about the $z$-axis. As I understand it, $\left|\langle\psi|Z_{\pi/2}|+\rangle\right|^2$ gives the probability of measuring the state $|\psi\rangle$ after applying $Z_{\pi/2}$ to $|+\rangle$. However, this seems to be a misinterpretation on my part; for example, consider the state
$$\left|\to\right> = Z_{\pi/2}|+\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle + i|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\,,$$
so that
$$\left|\langle +|Z_{\pi/2}|+\rangle\right|^2 = \frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$\left|\left<\to\right|\hspace{-0.2em}Z_{\pi/2}|+\rangle\right|^2 = 1\,.$$
Clearly, these probabilities do not work out *under my (flawed) interpretation*.

Furthermore, since our measurements ultimately result in $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, is it meaningful to speak of "the probability of measuring" a superposition state like $|+\rangle$?

**What is the correct interpretation of** $\left|\langle\psi|U|\phi\rangle\right|^2$ **in the context of qubits?**

Comment: Your |+> state is not an eigenstate of your rotation operator, I don't understand what's that got to do with the interpretation of measurement probabilities? You are calculating two different products and you are getting two different numbers.

Comment: It is absolutely normal to speak about a probability of measuring |+>. Imagine a photon in some polarization state. You can measure it in |H>, |V> basis, or in analogously defined |+> |-> basis, with polarizers oriented horizontally/vertically or right/left diagonally respectively.

Comment: The error is that your two measurement vectors aren't orthogonal, so there's no reason the probabilities should sum to one.

Comment: The eigenstates of the operator are just $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, in which case the expression looks like the expec. value (squared) equal to unity. The trouble is that I have seen these states and expressions used (e.g. in phase estimation) but I don't understand what they physically mean. If they aren't to be interpreted probabilistically, then how?

Comment: @Ilya, thanks, that clears up the fogginess I had about the measurement basis.